# Pause animation after its execution

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to pause animation with CSS after it was executed on hover and how?

As the result I want to have animation executed CSS selectors (that are mentioned in 100%) in a block on hover and when cursor leaves an area – animation has to be set back to 0.

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lfzu7gv/) what you are looking for? Your question isn't precise, please be more descriptive.

Comment: To me it seems quite a precise. I am talking about animation selector, not transition

Comment: My bad, sort of overlooked it. Anyway, does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lfzu7gv/9/) answer your question, unless I haven't mistaken this time too?

Comment: [Here is a link](https://codepen.io/alexa_wa/pen/xzqMvx)

Comment: What I want is this “+” to stay 35px sized while cursor is on the element without JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

https://codepen.io/nigelheap/pen/gKmydV